# Automatically Wrap Equations

Tags: equations, packages, wrap

Is there a LaTeX plugin that automatically wraps equations that are too wide, or is this something I must always do manually?

Comment: the `breqn` package was designed to do this, but it has problems.  it's generally better to do this manually, since you, as the author, *know* what the equation means, and that's very hard for an automated system, so your choice of breakpoint(s) is certain to provide a better presentation for conveying meaning.

Comment: See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172129/15925